# DirectX11 Present Hook get currently rendered frame

Tags: c++, rendering, hook, directx-11

I am hooking the DX Present function within a game and I want to get/capture the currently rendered frame before passing it to the real DXGI Present function.

I should add, the below code only runs ONCE when I press M (arbitrarily chosen key), not every frame. I forgot to mention that. I am only trying to get a single frame right now.

TLDR;
I get the Buffer, Create a texture from it and then try to create a ShaderResourceView from it, so that I can use ImGui to display it for debug purposes, however that last step always fails with E_INVALIDARGS. I've verified that all the pointers are correct (e.g. swapchain, device, devicecontext, etc).

Code:

```cpp
HRESULT hkDXGIPresent(IDXGISwapChain* pSwapChain, UINT SyncInterval, UINT Flags)
{
    // ...

    ID3D11Texture2D* pBackBuffer = nullptr;
    if (SUCCEEDED(pSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pBackBuffer))))
    {
        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
        pBackBuffer->GetDesc(&desc);

        desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
        desc.BindFlags = 0;
        desc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;

        ID3D11Texture2D* pStagingTexture;
        if (SUCCEEDED(pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&desc, nullptr, &pStagingTexture)))
        {
            pDeviceContext->CopyResource(pStagingTexture, pBackBuffer);

            D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc;
            ZeroMemory(&srvDesc, sizeof(srvDesc));
            srvDesc.Format = desc.Format;
            srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
            srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = desc.MipLevels;
            srvDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;

            if (SUCCEEDED(pDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(pStagingTexture, &srvDesc, &pCapturedSRV)))
            {
                // This is never reached, CreateShaderResourceView always returns HRESULT -> E_INVALIDARGS
            }

            pStagingTexture->Release();
        }

        pBackBuffer->Release();
    }

    return Hooks::DXGIPresent(pSwapChain, SyncInterval, Flags);
}
```

Comment: You need to turn on the debug layer, and then post the error https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps

Comment: Thank you, I'm a beginner with DirectX and this was the comment that lead me to the correct solution. All I had to do is set the correct flags for the description before copying. Those being CPUFlags = 0, BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE and Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT.